# Creating a generic web crawler in python for news aggregation like Flipboard

Tags: python, web-crawler

Recently I have been assigned a project at my college, which is a news aggregator. I found Flipboard to be a very interesting and viral app for news aggregation. To achieve this, I am building a web crawler, that  will crawl the websites, to fetch recent news and posts. I was going through a post on [Gizmod](http://www.gizmod.com)

> Is the scraper universal/generic, or are there customer scrapers for
>   certain sites?
>
> **Doll**: It is mostly universal/generic. However, we can
>   limit the amount of content displayed on a site-specific basis. We
>   already try to do this with some sites that publish extremely
>   abbreviated RSS feeds- even though we aren't using RSS directly, we
>   attempt to achieve display parity with their feed.

I am quite familiar with the process of fetching data from a single website. But not sure how could I fetch the data from multiple websites and blogs, all with a completely different structure.

I am currently using Python 2.7, urllib2 and BeautifulSoup for crawling a single website.

**Question:**

I want to know, how could I achieve the objective of fetching data from thousands of websites via just one generic crawler?

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Actually, I want to know, how could I achieve the objective of fetching data from thousands of websites via just one generic crawler?

Comment: So, ask that question.

Comment: sorry for that. I have updated the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend creating one big Spider class, then subclassing for individual sites. I wrote a short answer to a similar question [here on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31623593/scrapy-crawler-creating-a-10-000-spiders-or-one-spider-crawling-10-000-domains/31624331#31624331).

Answer (score 0):

I have done something similar, although having a basic knowledge of python and google-fu taught me how to make a script that the more advanced users would scoff at. But hey, it works for my use, and doesn't leave too much footprint.

I made several functions that used 'request' to fetch the sites and used 'beautifulsoup' to parse the individual sites based on the structure I reverse-engineered from the sites by using the inspector in Chrome.
When the script is run, it runs all of the functions, thus fetching the info I want.

Comment: what if, I wanted to scrape thousands of sites, like the Flipboard does. Won't this repeat the code too much?

Comment: Hmm, that's a little more complicated than my scripts.

Comment: Finally, we decided to go with the RSS feeds. Otherwise scraping the content without the permission might get us in trouble :) And RSS feeds seems simple to scrape.

Comment: Yes, jesus, I didn't think about RSS at all in this respect. Good work =)